# Milliseconds to DateTime in WP8 not working

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to convert a date in milliseconds to a user readable date and I can't.

My date is: 1494519599999 which corresponds to: Thu May 11 2017 18:19:59 GMT+0200

I need to get something like dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss

I have tried what I read in other stackoverflow posts:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(long.Parse(ticks));
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
```

But I always get 0 for year, month and more. I tought I should multiply or divide by 1000 the number but it was worst.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: what is the value of "long"? can you post it?

Comment: I did. It is 1494519599999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp seems to be the value often used in JavaScript to represent a date (the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1 1970). You can convert that to a `DateTimeOffset` using this code:

```
var timestamp = 1494519599999;
var epoch = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
var dateTimeOffset = epoch.AddMilliseconds(timestamp);
```

The result is `05/11/2017 16:19:59 +00:00`.

I am using a `DateTimeOffset` to make it easier for you to change the offset from `+0000` to `+0200`. You can change the offset using this code where I assume you want to convert to local date and time. Windows Phone 8 does not support the full functionality of the `TimeZoneInfo` class so if you need to convert to another time zone you need create code the explicitely changes the offset:

```
dateTimeOffset = dateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime();
```

Now the result is `05/11/2017 18:19:59 +02:00`.

If you prefer to use `DateTime` instead of `DateTimeOffset` you can use this code to create a UTC `DateTime`:

```
var timestamp = 1494519599999;
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dateTime = epoch.AddMilliseconds(timestamp);
```

The result is `05/11/2017 16:19:59` and if your local timezone has a offset of +0200 you can convert it to a local `DateTime` to get the desired result. However, when time zones are involved I suggest that you use `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: I don't have CreateCustomTimeZone in my TimeZoneInfo class. I can't use the second piece of code. Thanks for you time.

Comment: @Biribu: You haven't indicated exactly what you requirements are for the result. Do you need to convert it to a local time zone? Or to a specific time zone? Or use a specific offset as I do in my example? Or is it better to stick with UTC?

Comment: Yes sorry. I need +1 hour. I need timezone in Madrid.

Comment: @Biribu: I have changed my answer so the code now should compile on Windows Phone 8. However, I also have to assume that your code executes in the Madrid time zone (_Central Europe Standard Time_) and that you really want a local time result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
```

Comment: This command gave me: 17297.16:19:59.9990000 time is ok but year, month and day aren't I think. I have checked the real date with this page http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.VNHgAv6G_Je